# Viewcontroller's view fram doesn't give accuratly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using two approaches for to place my viewcontroller

Approach 1: Taking UIViewController and pushing the viewcontroller as like below `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`

Approach 2:Taking UIViewcontroller then I am using

```
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

While I am using the Approach1 "myViewController" view size giving as expected like portrait is  768*1024 coming to landscape is 1024*768.But the Approach2 is not providing the expected sizes as like first Approach, for both the orientations it is giving me 768*1024

Problem:
What is the issue in the second Approach? Is there any solution to over come the issue.

In the project I have to use second Approach only. But I need to get the correct dimensions.Provide me some suggestions.

My Viewcotrollers hierarchy:

1)My project based on UITabBarViewController and It is restricted to portrait only.

2)One of the UITabBarButton loads another ViewController ( BookBagViewController *bookBagViewController = [[BookBagViewController alloc] init];
    theNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookBagViewController];)

3)BookBagViewController is also restricted for portrait.

4)BookBagViewController contains one button once I click on it below code will be executed

```
MyViecontroller *viewer = [[MyViecontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViecontroller" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:viewer animated:YES];
```

5)MyViecontroller is supporting all the orientations as expected but not giving accurate frame size while printing (debugging).

6)For returning I am using below line

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For more info I provided above steps. Please accept it, even it is lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach:**

You are pushing the `UIViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController`. Besides the size of your `UIView` (which is the root of your `UIViewController`) you also need to remember the size of the `UINavigationBar` of the `UINavigationController`.

**Second Approach:**

You are presenting the full size of your `UIViewController` on the screen (you are not putting it inside of anything).

As for your problem, it's a bit weird the sizes are not actually updating according to the orientation. Could you show where you are printing those values?

Comment: Yes, your correct but according to my question How to get the landscape  frame as 1024*768 when I am getting 768*1024 in portrait.

Comment: How do you know the frame sizes are wrong (my point here is for you to show me where are you getting those values)?

Comment: NSLog(@"self.view.frame=%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame)); it is giving me (0,0,768,1024) for both the orientations. My view is occupying full screen in both the orientations.

Comment: Can you try with this: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

Comment: I am getting the dimensions as per the portrait even I use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; in landscape.What might be that issue

Comment: Where are you seeing the sizes? Try the following: Put those readings on `viewDidLoad` and presentViewController first in Portrait and then Landscape. Do **not** rotate the device once you are already inside the view.. Do the rotations before presenting.

Comment: when you are using present modal view controller , is your simulator supporting orientation ???
bcoz i remember once i was using this it didn't change the orientation then i used [self.view addSubview:anotherView]; instead of present modal view controller.... and navigation controller also support orientation..... let me know when u r using present modal view controller , is orientation being change or not ?